# Adding a checkbox to a component in Wicket

Tags: java, components, wicket

I have a Text field that when you write, autocompletes with the possible choices you have based on what you are writing.

There's a fixed list of favorite choices, and I have to add a checkbox to the component so the user can choose whether to see only the favourite choices or all the possible choices.

I asked google, but I can't find how to modify a component at that level.

Does anybody have hints or somewhere I can take a look at a good example?

Answer (score 0):

Add an AjaxCheckBox next to the text field. When the autocompleter asks the server for values use the AjaxCheckBox's model object to decide what to return.

Comment: Well, I have thought of that, but that is two separate components, and I wanted to build a component that has both the textfield and the checkbox in one.

Comment: Then see FormComponentPanel.